# How to split merged cell in BIRT

Tags: birt

I am trying to split a merged cell in BIRT Designer but there is no option to split.

I found that, this doesn't have solution at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=166197

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks,

Jayanth.

Comment: check the link you provided, the reporter says that, it was his mistake, so splitting works, but if you saved and close the report design after merging, the undo history will also be deleted so you cannot undo it. but you can split by right click on the cell and then choose split cell.

Answer (score 3):

This works as expected. Perhaps you made the same mistake as the poster in the mentioned link. You have to select the *cell*, not its content.
Once you have the cell selected, right-click and you can choose "Split Cell" from the context menu.

To select the cell, the easiest way is to use the breadcrumb bar (which is disabled by default, you can enable it with the mysterious symbol to the right of the zoom level list-box), and right-click the cell in the breadcrumb bar.

Another option is to move the cell's content somewhere else (temporarily) in order to empty the cell. Then split the cell, and move the content back into it.

Note 1: One would expect that it's possible to split the cell from the context menu in the Outline view, but no...

Note 2: You cannot modify the structure of a report item referenced from a library.